# Redirect 302 loop presumably because of load balancing and .NET Core auth

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, redis, .net-core, auth0

Technical details:

- .NET Core 2 application
- Auth0 for user storage
- Multiple instances hosted on AWS (Load balanced)
- Single Redis instance for caching

We are seeing infinite 302 redirects where we think each instance doesn't realise the user is either logged in or not logged in and bounces between our dashboard page and the login page.

We've tried forwarding the headers with x-forward-proto, set the application name for the data protection.

Comment: I've seen this with cookies and SSL before. Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Yeah we've tried the good old Ctrl + F5 and private browsing. Funnily enough, we activated sticky sessions for 12 days on the load balancer but this is only a work around and not a fix